# How to add credits for watching admob interstitial adds ios

Tags: ios, iphone, admob, interstitial

I've seen many apps in which users can unlock some features by watching video ads(users can earn coins or credits by watching video ads). Is it possible in ios by using AdMob? If yes, please help me by giving some links or sites about how to implement this properly.

Answer (score 1):

Following link may help you .

[GoogleAdSdk](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/advanced) , [ExampleProject](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/advanced), [FacebookAds](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-apps/) .etc. These are just help you to learn about earning via Ads.

Comment: I've went through those links that you provide. Now I'm able to show an interstitial ad in my ios application. but I cant find a way to add credits by checking if the user interacts with the ad.